# Getting a value from the JSON String

Tags: php, json

Please help me out with the code

1. I am getting the below result after I run my script which is working perfectly but I want to know how can I extract the value **true** which comes after the {"success":"

> {"success":"true","type":"API","totalprice":"1","totalgsm":"1","remaincredit":"491 SMS","results":[{"status":"OK","messageid":"263db4bc-321f-5d2e-8d3a-454bf0d2bda2","gsm":"923100000003"}]}

2. Here in my php code I want to have it checked if the value is returned as **true** it should run the first if statment and if the value is returned as **false** it should run the else statement.

   ```
   $ch = curl_init();
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $cpurl);
   curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
   curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
   $result = curl_exec ($ch);

   if (preg_match("/successfully/", $result ))
   {
   $alert = '<div class="alert alert-success">
                                       <button type="button" class="close" 
   data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                       <strong>Messages successfuly sent to 
   '.$cnt.' Students.</strong>
                                   </div>';
                                   $status = 'Success';

   }else{
     $alert = '<div class="alert alert-danger">
                                       <button type="button" class="close" 
   data-dismiss="alert" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                                       <strong>Message Sending Failed.</strong>
                                   </div>'; 
                                   $status = 'Failed';
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `json_decode`?

```
....
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
$response = json_decode($result);
```

Now you can access the value as `$response->success`:

```
if ($response->success === "true") { 
    $alert = ' × Messages successfuly sent to '.$cnt.' Students. '; 
    $status = 'Success';
} else { 
    $alert = ' × Message Sending Failed. '; $status = 'Failed'; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [JsonMapper](https://github.com/cweiske/jsonmapper) for solving the task. Just a define an object (view model) that will be the php representation of your json.